# React app 'Slowing down' when i try to dispatch action inside firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication in my React App.
I have buttons LogIn and LogOut, which are working correctly(i can console.log uid)
Redirecting is fine as well.
Then i tried to add new reducer 'user' : {uid: uid} or 'user': {} if logged out.
At this point my App doesn't want to run and browser shows the notification "A web page is slowing your browser".

Thats GitHub [link](https://github.com/evgeshabond/my-app-budget)

App.js:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Navigation from "../routers/Navigation";
import { firebase, database } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { startSetExpenses, setFiltersText } from "../redux/actions";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {logIn, logOut} from '../redux/actions'

let history = createBrowserHistory();

export function App(props) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      props.dispatch(logOut())
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      props.dispatch(logIn(user.uid))
      if (history.location.pathname === "/") {        
        history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Expenses App</h1>
      <Navigation history={history}/>
    </div>
  );
}

let mapStoreToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch
  }
}

export default connect(mapStoreToProps)(App)
```

---

RootReducer.js :

```
const initialState = {
  filters: {
      text: ""
  },
  expenses: [],
  user: {}
};

function userReducer(state = {}, action) {
  const {type, uid} = action
  switch (type) {
    case "LOGIN": 
      return {
        uid: uid
      }
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {}    
    default :
      return state;   

  }
}

function expensesReducer(state = initialState.expenses, action) {
  const { type,id, description, value, updates,expenses } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "ADD_EXPENSE":
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id,
          description,
          value,
        },
      ];
    case "REMOVE_EXPENSE":
      if (state.findIndex(expense => expense.id === id) < 0) throw new Error('index is not found')
      return state.filter((expense) => expense.id !== id);
    case "UPDATE_EXPENSE":
      return state.map((expense) => {
        return expense.id === id ? { ...expense, ...updates } : expense;
      });
    case "SET_EXPENSES":
      if (expenses) {
        return expenses
      }  
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function filtersReducer(state = initialState.filters, action) {
    const {type, text} = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 'SET_FILTERS_TEXT':
            return {...state, text}
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    filters: filtersReducer,
    expenses: expensesReducer,
    user: userReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

---

Actions.js:

```
import {database, firebase, googleProvider} from "../firebase/firebase";

export function logIn(uid) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('uid inside actionCreator', uid)
    dispatch({
      type: "LOGIN",
      uid: uid
    }) 
  }
  }

export function logOut() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('logged out')
    dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'})
  }
}

export function startLogIn() {
  return () => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider)    
  }
}

export function startLogOut() {
  return () => {
    return firebase.auth().signOut()
  }
}


export function addExpense({ id, description, value } = {}) {
  return {
    type: "ADD_EXPENSE",
    id,
    description,
    value,
  };
}

export const startAddExpense = (expense) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let newId = database.ref("expenses").push().key;
    const { description, value } = expense;
    return database
      .ref("expenses/" + newId)
      .set({ description, value })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(
          addExpense({
            type: "ADD_EXPENSE",
            id: newId,
            description,
            value,
          })
        );
      });
  };
};

export function removeExpense(id) {
  return {
    type: "REMOVE_EXPENSE",
    id,
  };
}

export const startRemoveExpense = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return database
      .ref("expenses/" + id)
      .remove()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("removing expense with id : " + id);
        dispatch(removeExpense(id));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Expense with id:${id} was not removed`);
        console.log(error)        
      });
  };
};

export function updateExpense(id, updates) {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_EXPENSE",
    id,
    updates,
  };
}

export const startUpdateExpense = (id, updates) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return database.ref('expenses/' + id)
    .update(updates)
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(updateExpense(id, updates))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error with updating an expense from firebase')
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}

export function setFiltersText(text) {
  return {
    type: "SET_FILTERS_TEXT",
    text,
  };
}

export const setExpenses = (expenses) => {
  return {
    type: "SET_EXPENSES",
    expenses: [...expenses],
  };
};

export const startSetExpenses = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    //get expenses from database
    //.then dispatch expenses to state with setExpenses
    return database
      .ref("expenses")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const expensesObj = snapshot.val();
        let expenses = [];
        for (let property in expensesObj) {
          expenses = [
            ...expenses,
            {
              id: property,
              description: expensesObj[property].description,
              value: expensesObj[property].value,
            },
          ];
        }
        dispatch(setExpenses(expenses));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you check the console? I would check if the `logIn(...)` action is called multiple times.

Comment: I think the problem is that firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() is incide App component. And when it changes state it produces infinite loop, but i don't know why. Btw i removed this from the Component in index.js file and now it is working. But the code looks really shitty.

Comment: Hi! You can try putting the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` inside a `useEffect` hook that only runs when the component mounts i.e something like `componentDidMount` in a functional component. This is so that the listener is only set once when the component mounts as opposed to every time the component renders.